# Merge two command results to one line when redirecting stdout

Tags: bash, stdout

In a cron script I want to log CPU temperatures in the format

```
[datetime] temp
```

using `date` and `acpi -t`. How can I redirect (`>>`) these two commands to a single line in the log file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try simply doing:

```
echo $(date) $(acpi -t) >> your_log_file
```

You might want to specify a compact date format to make your log file more easy to parse and to be independent of environment/locale settings (something like `$(date +"%Y%m%d %H%M%S")` for example).

Answer (score 4):

well perhaps on older systems (solaris8 f.e. ^^) without bash:

```
x=`date '+%Y%m%d %H%M%S'`; y=`acpi -t`; echo "$x $y" >>your_log_file
```

Comment: Even Solaris 8 understands `$(…)`, it's POSIX-compliant. But you have to use `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/sh`, Solaris 8's `/bin/sh` is still a Bourne shell.

Comment: Aaah, never used /usr/xpg4/bin/sh, we would have saved some efforts those days using just the Bourne shell.

Comment: Like this one...